# Run Rails script in cron job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

We want to run a Rails script (e.g., rails runner -e production script/test.rb) from a cron job, but it fails silently. The script works on its own when run from the command line.

Here is the line in our crontab: (This was set at 11:40 PM)

```
45 23 * * * rails runner -e production /home/t/T/script/ia.rb
```

What we doing wrong in running this Rails scripts from a cron job?

Thanks!

Contents of log file (after taking Ivan's suggestion):

```
[root@newvps T]# cat script/script.log
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                              # Default: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]   # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db)
                              # Default: sqlite3
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]     # Path to an application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]   # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--dev]                 # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-gemfile]        # Don't create a Gemfile
  -O, [--skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]      # Skip Test::Unit files
  -J, [--skip-prototype]      # Skip Prototype files
  -G, [--skip-git]            # Skip Git ignores and keeps

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Supress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Comment: log all output somewhere. So we can see what exactly is failing.

Comment: Try using the full path to the rails script, and make sure the user running the cron script can read `/home/t/T/script/ia.rb`

Comment: we have log statements inside, but nothing is being shown, @IvanDenisov.

Comment: isn't /home/t/T/script/ia.rb the full path @eugen

Comment: I meant the path to the rails executable, as in /usr/local/bin/rails or wherever that script was installed.

Comment: @Chashalot `45 23 * * * rails runner -e production /home/t/T/script/ia.rb > /path/to/log/file`
Your script doesn't get executed. That's why your inner log says nothing

Comment: @IvanDenisov just updated with log contents

Comment: probably, you will need to `cd` into directory with your application before running script.

Comment: To log errors use `command >> /tmp/mylog.log 2>&1` .  And keep in mind thay you need to maintain same environment (variables like $PATH, etc).

Comment: ok @taro, will try it

Comment: @taro The log now says "/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/rails runner -e production /home/t/T/script/ia.rb: No such file or directory" even though when we run the command on the command prompt, it works fine. Any clues?

Comment: Have you ever run the rails from a user from command line?

Comment: yes, if we run the same command as in the cron job it works from the command line.

Comment: Please inspect environments in shell and when using cron using command `env >> /tmp/myenvironment.txt`

Comment: Hmm, the file fails to get created. Does that mean the env aren't available to the cron job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At work, on the server, we run rails tasks with:

```
0 6 * * * bash -lc "cd /some_path && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production some_task"
```

maybe you need the **bash -lc** part and all the command inside " "

Comment: what does "bash -lc" do BTW?

Comment: you are excecuting a new bash instance, with -c you tell it to run the command on the string, check the docs for -l too http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash, if your server doesn't have bash you can use any terminal

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your command into quotes or use backslashes to mirror spaces

```
45 23 * * * "rails runner -e production /home/t/T/script/ia.rb"
```

or

```
45 23 * * * rails\ runner\ -e\ production\ /home/t/T/script/ia.rb
```

instead of

```
45 23 * * * rails runner -e production /home/t/T/script/ia.rb
```

Comment: Hmmm adding the double quotes only resulted in an empty log file ... other suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry, just don't have time to check all the possible options, but I bet one of them or combination would work.
Also try `\`rails runner -e production /home/t/T/script/ia.rb\``

Comment: The log now says "/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/rails runner -e production /home/t/T/script/ia.rb: No such file or directory" even though when we run the command on the command prompt, it works fine. Any clues?